# Hibernate - How to set lazy property dynamically through coding

Tags: hibernate

I set lazy property as "true" in my hbm mapping file. However I want to change "lazy=false" dynamically through code. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either joins via HQL or `FetchMode.JOIN` via Criteria API, in this case you'll get your associations in a single shot. Note, that associated objects won't be fetched from 2nd level cache if you use it.

Another option is `Hibernate.initialize()` or simply just invoke `object.getAssociation()`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(YourClass.class)`. It has the methods to access every field.

The more civilized way, however, is to override fetching strategy with HQL or Criteria query. Another option is to modify your metadata (having `lazy="false"`) and rebuild the session factory. It's not that scary as it looks like.